# Object(...)(...).takeUntil is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have my observable with interval and takeuntil which is working fine in angular 5. Now When I update it to angular 6 and rxjs6, it is failing. 
I changed from Observable.interval to interval but takeuntil is not working.
I need takeuntil because, I need to stop this observable when the component is destroyed.

```
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

private onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();

Observable.interval(600000).takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(x => {
    // do something
});

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy$.next();
}
```

Comment: Since RxJS 6 use pipable operators. `import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since RXJS 6, you have to pipe the operators and import them from `rxjs/operators`.
Also, you have to use `interval` and not `Observable.interval`, [see this doc for more info](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html):

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs;
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

interval(600000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
).subscribe(x => {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's

```
Observable.interval(600000).pipe(
   takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
).subcribe(//...
```